# Getting current scheduler information for Android app using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, bufferedreader, scheduler

I'm trying to get the current scheduler information from the path "/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler" to be output in my application. However, it doesn't seem to return anything, not sure what I am doing wrong here?\

```
    private String getScheduler() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    String file = "/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler";  // Gets governor for big cores

    if (new File(file).exists()) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file)));
            String aLine;
            while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(aLine + "\n");
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (sb.toString().length() == 0) {
        return "File not available";
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It always return the string "File not available". I know this should work as I did the same thing for returning the current scaling governor. Do I need to request for root permissions within this app, even though my phone is already rooted?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!